# Rewriting URL with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have Wordpress plugin that provides page translation to users by placing the Google translate tool on their website. I want to add url rewrite capability so that when language is changed, the url is re-written.

I have PHP/HTML code that changes languages by using simple links with fire events, like this:

```
<a href="#" class="nturl en" onclick="doGoogleLanguageTranslator('en|en'); return false;" title="English"><span class="flag"><img class="flagimg flagselect colorbox-4242" src="http://wp-studio.net/wp-content/plugins/google-language-translator/images/flags24/unitedkingdom.png" height="16" width="16" alt="English"/></span>English</a>
```

How would I go about adding this url rewrite functionality, based on the way I have implemented this?  Can I do this by adding stuff to `.htaccess`, or do I need to reconfigure things to get started on this?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want the URL to look, both before and after?

Comment: @jerdiggity, Sure...great point.....I would like url to be something like: `http://www.example.com/page/de/`

Comment: I assume that's the "after", making the "before" something like `http://www.example.com/page/en/` -- is that correct?

Comment: @jerdiggity, yes that's correct, although when user first loads the page in default "English", it probably won't have the `en` appended to the url.  But if this is the only way for now, I do not care.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming all the logic to translate the page is done via javascript on the page itself. In that case, you only need an internal rewrite in .htaccess that translates `/pages/language/` to `/pages`. In the url will still `/pages/language/` be displayed.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(en|de|fr|qq)$ $1 [L]
```

See [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for more information.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  Actually, the logic for translation is done through `element.js`, which is a Google provided file that is cut/pasted into the page.  Does that make things different here?

Comment: I have no clue; I have never used that before.